# How to make logarithmic axes in plot3d (library("rgl")) in R?

Tags: r, rgl

I am having extreme difficulty in making my axes logarithmic/have custom tick marks in plot3d using the rgl package.   I've tried using the "log='xy'" command in my code just like you would in the basic plot function, and I have tried to create custom tick marks using rgl.bbox.  My y axis is plotting fine but my x and z are not cooperating.  I cannot get anything to work.  Any ideas?  Below is my data, code, and a picture of the result I'm getting.  I should also add that I'm basically plotting multiple 2d scatterplots in 3d using an arbitrary z value to separate the individual 2d plots.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wv24rmnyalm3vvc/scattertest.csv?dl=0

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library("rgl")

data <- read.csv("~/Desktop/scattertest.csv", header=TRUE, fill=TRUE, sep=',')

x <- names(data[2])
y <- names(data[3])
z <- names(data[4])

plot3d(data[[x]], data[[z]], data[[y]], type="s", size=0.75, lit=FALSE, axes=FALSE, 
   xlab="rpmn", ylab="round", zlab="rpmt", log="xz",
   xmin=c(0.1, 10^6), ymin=c(1,4), zmin=c(0.1, 10^6))


rgl.bbox(color="grey50", emission="grey50",
     xat = c(0.1, 1, 10, 100, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5, 10^6), yat = c(1, 2, 3, 4), zat = c(0.1, 1, 10, 100, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5, 10^6), 
     xlen=8, ylen=4, zlen=8)
```

[image: results from code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no support for `log="xy"` in `plot3d()`, you'll need to do the transformation yourself.

Your code asks for logarithmic labels, but you aren't doing the logarithmic transformation, so it's not working.  You need to rescale the data as well.

You didn't post a reproducible example, but it's easy to create one:

```
x <- rlnorm(20, 2, 6)
y <- runif(20, 1, 4)
z <- rlnorm(20, 2, 6)
xyz <- cbind(log(x), y, log(z))
plot3d(xyz, axes = FALSE)
ticks <- 10^((-1):6)
bbox3d(xat = log(ticks), xlab = ticks, yat = pretty(1:4), 
       zat = log(ticks), zlab = ticks,
       color="grey50", emission="grey50")
```

[image: sample output]